# work with Credit Memo Magento API using C#

Tags: c#, magento

As in the title, I am trying to create a Credit Memo on already created order. I have Magento GO, and I am able to pull down order, create shipment, create invoice but there are no object to work with credit memos. I checked the XML file with service schema and clearly the schema has no information about the memos.

I've read that this API doesn't exist, but Magento's API documentation clearly states that it does: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderCreditMemo/salesOrderCreditMemo.html

Do I need to update my XML somehow or should there be some other way to do it. Link to the XML: http://demo.magentocommerce.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

Could it be the difference between Magento GO solution and Enterprise one?

Any advise would be helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done credit order api for magento 1.4.1.1 cose I was in need also,, so aparrently the core theme didn't do it then. It was added in the newer versions :(

I don't know how can you use it in go version...

You can get it from here, but I guess you have to add method for creading memos,, I have only for list and info.

https://github.com/mkdizajn/magento-1.4-creditmemo-api

hth, cheers

Comment: Yes you are right. I requested an API upgrade and, surprisingly, they did it. Now my API does include credit memo entities.